# Extract nested value from a Django jsonfield

Tags: django, postgresql

Is there a way to query an object, 'extract' a nested piece of data from a `JSONField` field and then make it available as a custom, temporary field on each instance of the Queryset?

In my use case, I'm storing overflow metadata from Twitter's API in a `data` field for later use. I'd like to be able to access the nested field `followers_count` within `TwitterPost.data`.

I've read the docs about how to filter based on nested values but not how to extract it as a temporary field when generating a queryset.

Similarly, I've read the `annotate` docs for ways to create a custom temporary field but the examples all use aggregation functions on simple fields, so not `JSONFields`.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Example model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class TwitterPost(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    data = JSONField()
```

Example JSON value for the `data` field:

```
{
  'followers_count': 7172,
  "default_profile_image": false,
  "profile_text_color": "000000"
}
```

Pseudocode for what I'd like to be able to do:

```
TwitterPost.objects.annotate(followers_count=instance.data.followers_count)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably a late answer, but there is a way to do it

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import KeyTransform

TwitterPost.objects.annotate(followers_count=KeyTransform('followers_count', 'data'))
```

OR KeyTextTransform could be used instead of KeyTransform (for converting to string)

Comment: Yes,  this got added in a later version of Django (1.11 IIRC) and I've been using it since asking this question. Thanks for leaving the answer for future searchers.

Comment: I believe the order of arguments to KeyTextTransform is (json_key_name, jsonfield_name), so it would be `KeyTextTransform('followers_count', 'data')`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the data inside a JSONField, you've to use __. In your example it will be something like this

```
TwitterPost.objects.annotate(followers_count=instance.data__followers_count)
```

Take a look to the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield)